# AuthorizeLevel could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Hello i am in the "get started with authentication in mobile services" step right now trying to build my app.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-phone-get-started-users/

i add the attribute this why:

[AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)]
  public class TodoItemController : TableController

but i get error.

is there anything i should do that not mention in the tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are a mistake in the official documentation.

The correct atribute is RequiresAuthorization

[RequiredAuthorization(AuthorizationLevel.User)]

Answer (score 0):

The AuthorizeLevel attribute can be found in the NuGet package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend. Please add that package using the Package Manager Console, or search for "Microsoft Azure Mobile Services .NET Backend" in the package manager dialog.